# Reading most significant byte

Tags: c, networking, memory

I'm trying to write a simple check whether an IP address is valid

```
bool is_unicast_address(struct in_addr address)
{
    uint32_t value        = ntohl(address.s_addr);
    const uint8_t *octets = (const uint8_t *)&value;
    
    /*A few checks just for now */
    if (octets[3] == 0 /*net 0*/) {
        return false;
    } else if (octets[3] == 127 /*loopback*/) {
        return false;
    } else if (octets[3] >= 224 /*multicast etc*/) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The assumption is that *address* argument is in network byte order, and my understanding it that this is a convention C for *struct in_addr*. Now if so, is this code portable? I understand that because my machine is little endian, this works fine.
But if I run this code on a big-endian machine, this *ntohl* macro will do nothing, and *octets[3]* will point to an invalid value?

So should I use *ntohl* macro in scenarios like this?

Edit: If I'm correct removing the nthol, and accessing octets[0] will make this code portable. But that just complicates things, because it raises questions "*for some reason there is no ntohl, and in other functions there is*". So is there a way to use *ntohl* and still make it portable?

Comment: `ntohl` converts the net address (big end.) to what the host app uses, so little endian in your case. The portable way to get the high-order byte from that value will be something like `((value & 0xFF000000) >> 24)`.

Comment: (actually the `&` is redundant here, since this is the most significant byte)